# In nginx, how to separate https://app from http://www and redirect

Tags: nginx

My system has a secure area at https://app.domainname.org and also http://www.domainname.org.  I have seen many posts referring to similar but slightly different problems/configurations.

How can I, using nginx, ensure that requests to the right url but the wrong protocol are automagically fixed?

For example:

1. Requests to http://app.domainname.org/file.html are transparently redirected to https://app.domainname.org/file.html
2. Request to https://www.domainname.org/file.html are transparently redirected to http://www.domainname.org/file.html

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name app.domianname.org;

  rewrite ^(.*) https://$server_name$1 permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

  server_name www.domianname.org;

  rewrite ^(.*) http://$server_name$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Hello, this approach led to Chrome saying "This is probably not the site you are looking for!". The other problem is that the http:// protocol prefix disappeared - it would be good if the protocol prefix remained in place.

Comment: Chrome hides the http:// prefix, so you can't change that. You will get that error in Chrome if you're using a self-signed certificate because it's not trusted by your machine.